# Lack of motion in my loco motion chart

Tags: d3.js

I'm trying to adapt Mike Bostock's [Wealth of Nations](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/nations/) motion chart example to my own data set. Funny enough, I'm using GPS lata/long from train locomotives as the axes and datetimes instead of years.

Have a look at my jsfiddle [(link)](http://jsfiddle.net/3dMhS/5/).

This seems to be the key part to actually move the dots, but I'm not actually getting any motion.

```
  // Add a dot per loco. Initialize the data at min(starttime), and set the colors.
    var dot = svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "dots")
        .selectAll(".dot")
        .data(interpolateData(minDateInt))
        .enter().append("circle")
        .attr("class", "dot")
        .style("fill", function(d) { return colorScale(color(d)); })
        .call(position)
        .sort(order);

  // Positions the dots based on data.
  function position(dot) {
    dot .attr("cx", function(d) { return xScale(x(d)); })
        .attr("cy", function(d) { return yScale(y(d)); })
        .attr("r", function(d)  { return radiusScale(radius(d)); });
```

Does anyone know what's wrong with my code?

[image]

Comment: from the fiddle the date is not parsed correctly and returns NaN

Comment: Ahhh rats. It must be something to do with how I have the fiddle set up. I'll post the full index.html when I get to work.

Comment: I just noticed that in Safari it still gives NaN, while in Chrome the date is formatted properly, sorry maybe it worked even before

Comment: I can't really track down the error honestly, but for now I found that there's a typo on function y(d) it says "latititude" where it should be latitude. I'll keep making some tries

Comment: I still believe the error(s) are in the date parsing, because all the rest of the code looks like the one in the example. Unfortunately I can't be of any help with date parsing since I'm not very familiar with that, but yeah I would start looking there for any problems. (since safari keeps telling me the date is NaN the values for the dots are not correctly cumputed, so my best guess is something is wrong there)